# IconButton color does not change (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, iconbutton

I have a TextField widget for a password field and an IconButton for showing/hiding the password. What I want is that when the user taps on the IconButton, it should change color. It does actually, when I run `print(showPassWordIconColor)` before and after clicking the IconButton, its value changes. However it does not display the changed color.
I have seen some other questions and their answers, and I tried them but I still get the same problem.
Here is the full widget.
(initially showPasswordIconColor = Colors.grey)

```
Widget passwordField = AppTextFormField(
  obscureText: !_showPassword,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Password",
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.remove_red_eye,
        color: showPasswordIconColor,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          _showPassword = !_showPassword;
          if (showPaswswordIconColor == Colors.grey) {
            showPaswswordIconColor = buttonColor;
          } else {
            showPaswswordIconColor = Colors.grey;
          }
          print(showPaswswordIconColor);
        });
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: where is showPaswswordIconColor method?

Comment: It is a variable of type Color defined on top of the file. I can reach it and change it in the setState(), but the displayed color does not change.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Please check the below code.

Then use the below code.

```
Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            child: TextFormField(
              obscureText: !_showPassword,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Password",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.remove_red_eye,
                    color: showPasswordIconColor,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _showPassword = !_showPassword;
                      if (showPasswordIconColor == Colors.grey) {
                        showPasswordIconColor = Colors.red;
                      } else {
                        showPasswordIconColor = Colors.grey;
                      }
                      print(showPasswordIconColor);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Comment: I already declared them as variables on top of the file and as I mentioned, I can reach those variables within my widget. I can update the _showPassword and showPasswordIconColor variables. But I can not update the visible color of the IconButton

Comment: ok, not check this code, it is already edited and working on my file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ThemeData you can apply a schema like this.

```
inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        iconColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
          if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused)) {
            return Colors.green;
          }
          if (states.contains(MaterialState.error)) {
            return Colors.red;
          }
          return Colors.green;
        }
        ),
      )
```